# SMS for small screen - workarounds or replacement app

Tags: sms, screen

The default SMS app's text size on my current phone is far too big for my tiny screen, and it wastes further screen real estate with a suggestion bar, which isn't much good if you can't see what you're replying to or half of what you're typing. Also, it inserts the name of the addressee and their *phone number* at the top of the screen unless you're actually scrolling.

Currently, I spend more time trying to see what's written than I do typing.

Could anyone offer any advice, or alternatively, is there an Eclair-compatible SMS app which

1. Allows the user to specify text size, or uses small text to begin with
2. Provides a good view of what you're writing and/or reading.

Any suggestions for smaller-but-still-usable keypads would also be appreciated.

I already know that the keypad can be temporarily hidden whilst composing a message, but it's useful to be able to see a little of both messages whilst 
actually typing.

This is really bugging me.

Thanks :-)

Comment: Haven't you tried HandCent, Go SMS pro or SMSdroid? There's a huge list of 3rd party SMS apps available on the market.

Comment: @ce4 Thanks for the suggestions. I had tried several other SMS apps before asking the question. Unfortunately SMS Droid and Go SMS Pro hide everything whilst a message is being composed (SMS Droid covers up the message with adverts), and Handcent has smaller text but then doesn't use the full width of the screen, and thus isn't much better for either the previous message or the one being written. They also all require a LOT of permissions and are quite bloated. However, thanks for suggesting Go SMS Pro as I can now at least see what I'm writing. :-)

Comment: SMSdroid is an ad supported open source SMS app, but an adless [version of SMSdroid](https://f-droid.org/repository/browse/?fdid=de.ub0r.android.smsdroid) is available on F-Droid.org that has been stripped of the ad "feature". You can also use [F-Droid's market app](https://f-droid.org/FDroid.apk) to install the ad-less SMSdroid. SMSdroid can be tweaked to have a non-bloated view, also. Alas, the many permissions are needed for the functionality of SMS apps (plus "internet" to load ads, if the app is ad supported).